Outlook Redemption AddPSTStore Error MAPI_E_INTERFACE_NOT_SUPPORTED
I am working with Outlook Nicknames using Redemption for a C# .NET Framework console application. When I attempt to add a PST store with:
RDOPstStore pstStore = rdoSession.Stores.AddPSTStore(@"c:\Support\nicknames.pst", 1, "Test Store");
I receive the error:

Error in IMsgServiceAdmin::AdminProviders:
MAPI_E_INTERFACE_NOT_SUPPORTED

Here is the relevant code:
using System;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Redemption;

RDOSession rdoSession = new RDOSession();
rdoSession.MAPIOBJECT = new Outlook.Application().Session.MAPIOBJECT;

RDOStore defaultStore = rdoSession.Stores.DefaultStore;
RDOPstStore pstStore = rdoSession.Stores.AddPSTStore(@"c:\Support\nicknames.pst", 1, "Test Store");

RDONicknames defaultNicknames = rdoSession.GetNicknames();
RDONicknames pstNicknames = pstStore.GetNicknames();
pstNicknames.Clear();

foreach (RDONickName nickname in defaultNicknames)
{
    pstNicknames.Add(nickname.GetAddressEntry());
}

pstNicknames.Save();

foreach (RDONickName nickname in pstNicknames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nickname.Name + "_" + nickname.SMTPAddress);
}
Console.ReadLine();

I experimented with the Catastrophic Failure trying to AddPstStore solution, however this did not apply to my situation.
All suggestions and assistance welcome.

You end up using IMAPISession from the outlook.exe process, and MAPI cannot handle marshaling IMsgServiceAdmin interface across process boundaries.
You can either

Create MAPI session in the same process - instead of setting the rdoSession.MAPIOBJECT property, call rdoSession.Logon:

rdoSession.Logon(new Outlook.Application().Session.CurrentProfileName);

You can also call Logon with no parameters to log to the default profile.

Create rdoSession inside the outlook.exe process space. This has an extra benefit of letting the bitness of your process be different from that of Outlook:

var app = new Outlook.Application();
RDOSession rdoSession = app.CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession");
rdoSession.MAPIOBJECT = app.Session.MAPIOBJECT;


Thanks Dmitry. when I try the first option, I get an"Already Logged on" exception.
When I try the second, I get a System.InvalidCastException:
Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Redemption.RDOSession'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{E54C5168-AA8C-405F-9C14-A4037302BD9D}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

For the first error, that means you did not comment out the line setting the MAPIOBJECT property. For the second error, please show your code - I suspect you are assigning app variable to rdoSession.

Thanks Dmitry, I very much appreciate your help. The first option now works. The second option starts with the three lines of code you provided (replacing therdoSession creation/MAPI object assignation in my code) and issues the error on RDOSession rdoSession = app.CreateObject("Outlook.Application"); I wish there were a way to run Redemption nicknames code while Outlook was launched, however am I correct that that's not possible due to the autocomplete stream being in memory?

@joeschwa - I am sorry, my bad: that line is supposed to be RDOSession rdoSession = app.CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession"); Outlook usually reloads the autocomplete stream if sees the cache as updated. Does Outlook ignore your changes?

Thanks Dmitry, the code correction removed the InvalidCastException error. And yes, Outlook does seem to be ignoring my changes whether Outlook is running or not. When I run my code while Outlook is running I get a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)). Can I force Outlook to reload the autocomplete stream?

Dmitry, I have resolved the error mentioned in my previous comment. That was being raised due to my VS 2022 IDE running as admin and Outlook not running as admin: Why am I receiving exception from Office's Outlook library?. So my code runs without exceptions being raised, however Outlook ignores any changes (I've attempted property changes and rdoSession.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveName(nickname.SMTPAddress to update nicknames from GAL). Any additional assistance on this last issue would be greatly appreciated.

But you do see the changes after restarting Outlook, right?

Restarting Outlook does not bring in the changes. I was able to bring in changes after restarting Outlook several times, however I was not able to replicate this with the same type of change (AddressBook.GAL.ResolveName in this case) for another contact. I question if the one time I was successful was due to some other process. When I debug, the changes are happening. Either pstNicknames.Save is failing (there are no exceptions) or Outlook is not accepting the changes.

But do you see the changes if you access the nicknames through Redemption after modifying them?

Yes, any changes made are added to pstNicknames and can then be utilized by Redemption via the RDONickNames collection or the individual nicknames. I just cannot save the changes to Outlook so they are part of the autocomplete entries that are accessed by users addressing messages.

Oh, wait, but the PST store is not the default one in Outlook, is it?

No pstStore is not the default. rdoSession.MAPIOBJECT = app.Session.MAPIOBJECT ties the session to Outlook. RDOPstStore pstStore = rdoSession.Stores.AddPSTStore ties the session to the PST store.  Nicknames from default store added or added with changes to pstStore nicknames. pstNicknames.Save(); Am I missing something here?

But Outlook will never look at the nicknames from the PST store.

So you are saying that I cannot use Redemption to make changes to Outlook nicknames and have those changes reflected in Outlook's autocomplete because Outlook only looks at the default store and there is no means to edit nicknames directly in the default store or copy them from the PSTStore to the default store. Thanks Dmitry.

But you can use Redemption to modify nicknames in the primary store.

Thanks Dmitry. I have had to switch to another project for the moment so I will not currently be able to test if I can modify nicknames in the primary store and then copy them to the default store so the changes can be reflected in Outlook's autocomplete. I hope to circle back to this in the coming weeks. Very much appreciate all your help!
